# Export Powershell to txt file

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that I run and  would like it to export to a txt file when completed. But it should not overwrite the existing output file  Any suggestions?

```
tracert  9.9.9.9
tracert  1.1.1.1
tracert  8.8.4.4
tracert  149.112.112.112
tracert  8.8.8.8
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add the cmdlet `Start-Transcript` to the script to have any output it generates recorded in a text file.

Alternatively you could save and run the script and then redirect its output to a file:

```
.\yourscript.ps1 > output.txt
```

Or within the script you could capture the output of your commands and then use a cmdlet like `Out-File` to to send the result to file.

Answer (score 1):

Normally there's an easy difference between overwriting and appending a file:

```
>output.txt  // overwrite
>>output.txt // append
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what version of PowerShell you are using and what OS you are using, there is a built-in PowerShelCmdlet for this.

```
'9.9.9.9','1.1.1.1','8.8.4.4','149.112.112.112','8.8.8.8' | 
ForEach {Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $PSItem -TraceRoute} |
Out-File -FilePath 'D:\Temp\TraceRoutReport.csv' -Append
```

You could do the same approach with the what you are doing as well. Yet, if you are in PowerShell, use the cmdlets.

[Windows PowerShell equivalents for common networking commands (IPCONFIG, PING, NSLOOKUP, TRACERT)](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/josebda/2015/04/18/windows-powershell-equivalents-for-common-networking-commands-ipconfig-ping-nslookup/)

> TRACERT
>
> Description: Trace route. Shows the IP route to a host, including all
>   the hops between your computer and that host. PowerShell:
>   Test-NetConnection –TraceRoute
>
> Sample command lines:

```
Test-NetConnection www.microsoft.com –TraceRoute
Test-NetConnection outlook.com -TraceRoute | Select -ExpandProperty TraceRoute | % { Resolve-DnsName $_ -type PTR -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue }
```

Sample output:

```
PS C:\> Test-NetConnection www.microsoft.com –TraceRoute
ComputerName           : www.microsoft.com
RemoteAddress          : 104.66.197.237
InterfaceAlias         : Wi-Fi
SourceAddress          : 192.168.1.2
PingSucceeded          : True
PingReplyDetails (RTT) : 16 ms
TraceRoute             : 192.168.1.1
                         10.0.0.1
                         TimedOut
                         68.86.113.181
                         69.139.164.2
                         68.85.240.94
                         68.86.93.165
                         68.86.83.126
                         104.66.197.237
PS C:\> Test-NetConnection outlook.com -TraceRoute | Select -ExpandProperty TraceRoute | % { Resolve-DnsName $_ -type PTR -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue }
Name                           Type   TTL   Section    NameHost
----                           ----   ---   -------    --------
125.144.85.68.in-addr.arpa     PTR    7200  Answer     te-0-1-0-10-sur02.bellevue.wa.seattle.comcast.net
142.96.86.68.in-addr.arpa      PTR    4164  Answer     be-1-sur03.bellevue.wa.seattle.comcast.net
6.164.139.69.in-addr.arpa      PTR    2469  Answer     be-40-ar01.seattle.wa.seattle.comcast.net
165.93.86.68.in-addr.arpa      PTR    4505  Answer     be-33650-cr02.seattle.wa.ibone.comcast.net
178.56.167.173.in-addr.arpa    PTR    7200  Answer     as8075-1-c.seattle.wa.ibone.comcast.net
248.82.234.191.in-addr.arpa    PTR    3600  Answer     ae11-0.co2-96c-1a.ntwk.msn.net
```

Comment: Is it possible to add the date into each of the times I run the tracert on those IP addresses?

Comment: Yes, just either use get-date and format that string as needed, then add as part of the file name.